# How to integrate PayPal form into wordpress website?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, paypal

I have my site page https://fluxanimations.com/price/

I have added the following code by copying form another site. here is the code.

```
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="WAAW46YTG7GRE">
<table>
<tbody><tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Whiteboard Video">Whiteboard Video</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
<option value="30 seconds">30 seconds $598.00 USD</option>
<option value="60 seconds">60 seconds $1196.00 USD</option>
<option value="90 seconds">90 seconds $1794.00 USD</option>
<option value="120 seconds">120 seconds $2392.00 USD</option>
<option value="150 seconds">150 seconds $2990.00 USD</option>
<option value="180 seconds">180 seconds $3588.00 USD</option>
  <option value="210 seconds">210 seconds $4178.00 USD</option>
  <option value="240 seconds">240 seconds $2486.00 USD</option>
  <option value="270 seconds">270 seconds $5385.00 USD</option>
  <option value="300 seconds">300 seconds $5984.00 USD</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</tbody></table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/SG/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I changed the option field values, but it is fetching the old values.

I want to know that how can I integrate this form to my PayPal account like when users will click the Buy button and pay the payment should transfer into my PayPal account.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is a hosted button:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="WAAW46YTG7GRE">
```

So, it will fetch the values set for this button in the PayPal account.

If you want different values, you need to create a new button (or edit this button in http://www.paypal.com/buttons , but that will affect any other sites using it).

If you copied the button from a site that you don't own, i.e. it is not your button, then you should create your own button at http://www.paypal.com/buttons -- logging into your own PayPal account before doing so.